# Override method implementation declared in an interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I've got an interface with a several methods in it.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    //...
    void OnItemClicked()
    //...
}
```

And an implementation

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    //Other methods
    public void OnItemClicked(){ /*...*/ } 
}
```

Now, I want to have a class that behaves like `MyClass` except of `OnItemClicked()`, I want some modifications for this method.

I thought to inherit an override but I don't want to change the `MyClass` (like: public **`virtual`** void OnItemClicked()...) because its not my implementation,

I don't want to implement `IMyInterface` again because the OnItemClicked() is the only part of MyClass to modify.

Do I have any other way to do it?

Comment: Create an intermediate class between these two.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you are implementing an interface, polymorphism is probably something you'd like to keep. It's impossible to override the method without modyfing the base class with a virtual, so you must use new instead of virtual as Tigran wrote.

This means that writing this kind of code but only the base version of the method would be executed:

```
List<MyClass> aList = new List<MyClass>();
aList.Add(new MyClass());
aList.Add(new MyNewClass());
foreach (MyClass anItem in aList)
    anItem.OnItemClicked();
```

To execute the right code you should write ugly code like this:

```
List<MyClass> aList = new List<MyClass>();
aList.Add(new MyClass());
aList.Add(new MyNewClass());
foreach (MyClass anItem in aList)
{
    MyNewClass castItem = anItem as MyNewClass;
    if (castItem != null)
        castItem.OnItemClicked();
    else
        anItem.OnItemClicked();
}
```

Anyway there is a way to have your classes executing the right method when they are assigned to variables declared as IMyInterface. The way to go is to explicitly implement the part of the interface that you want to override, in your case the OnItemClicked method. The code is the following:

```
public class MyNewClass : MyClass, IMyInterface // you MUST explicitly say that your class implements the interface, even if it's derived from MyClass
{
    public new void OnItemClicked() //NEW keyword here you have the overridden stuff
    { 
        /*...*/ 
    } 

    void IMyInterface.OnItemClicked() // No need for public here (all interfaces's methods must be public)
    { 
        this.OnItemClicked(); 
    } 
}
```

In this way:

```
 MyClass cl = new MyNewClass(); 
 cl.OnItemClicked();
```

executes the base method

```
 MyNewClass cl = new MyNewClass(); 
 cl.OnItemClicked();
```

executes the method of the derived class

```
 IMyInterface cl = new MyNewClass(); 
 cl.OnItemClicked();
```

executes the method of the derived class and is bound at runtime. This means that you can write the code of my initial example like this and have the right methods executed:

```
List<IMyInterface> aList = new List<IMyInterface>();
aList.Add(new MyClass());
aList.Add(new MyNewClass());
foreach (IMyInterface anItem in aList)
    anItem.OnItemClicked();
```

Answer (score 5):

you can derive from  `MyClass`

```
public class MyNewClass : MyClass
{
    public new void OnItemClicked(){ /*...*/ } //NEW keyword
}
```

The only thing, pay attention that in this way you do not supprot polymorphism.

To be more clear:

```
     MyClass cl = new MyNewClass(); 
     cl. MyMethod();
```

this will call `MyClass` method, even if the *real* object type is `MyNewType`.
To be able to call what we want, we have to esplicitly define type

```
     MyNewClass cl = new MyNewClass(); 
     cl. MyMethod(); //WILL CALL METHOD WE WANT
```

Comment: He mentioned in his post: I thought to inherit an override but I don't want to change the MyClass (like: public virtual void OnItemClicked()...) because its not my implementation,

Comment: @armen.shimoon: infact he didn't. Where do you see the code that changes MyClass implementation ?

Comment: My bad Tigran. I glanced over the code and thought you had "override" instead of "new". Question: when MyNewClass is used as an instance of "IMyInterface", which method will be called?

Comment: @armen.shimoon: Look in my post example. There is no polymorphism support for this feature.

Comment: I suppose interfaces are polymorphism. Makes sense. I guess it depends on his usage now.

Comment: take a look at explicit implementation of interfaces for polymorphism

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create a new class that mimics "is-a" using "has-a":

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void OnItemClicked();
    void OnItemHover();
    void OnItemDoubleClicked();
}

public class MyNewClass : IMyInterface
{
    private IMyInterface _target;

    public MyNewClass(IMyInterface target)
    {
        _target = target;
    }

    public void OnItemClicked()
    {
        // custom functionality
    }

    public void OnItemHover()
    {
        _target.OnItemHover();
    }

    public void OnItemDoubleClicked()
    {
        _target.OnItemDoubleClicked();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but you can't assign this to a MyClass variable

Comment: Yes, but in the answer where you can assign it to a MyClass variable and you called OnItemClicked() it would execute the wrong function. I was assuming the interface was the important part, otherwise this would not work correctly, but neither would the other answer.

Comment: You're right, in fact, I prefer your answer to the other, I was just pointing out why I prefer my answer to yours :-)

Answer (score 1):

use pattern bridge http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern

Comment: links disappear. Keep this kind of answers as comments, please